# WooCommerce: Adding a setup fee to certain products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

As the questions implies I want to add a setup-fee for certain products. The additional fee should be displayed in the product mask, cart and checkout. How is it possible to get that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-fees/) plugin. It's very easy. If you want to display the setup fee in your product description, use the following code:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$fee_name   = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-name', true );
$fee_amount = get_post_meta( $id, 'product-fee-amount', true );
echo $fee_name . ' - ' . $fee_amount;
```